# Pandas: compare two columns and return matched rows

Tags: pandas, match, dataframe, vlookup

I have two dataframes with multiple columns.

I would like to compare df1['postcode'] and df2['pcd'] and build a new df based on the matched values of these two columns.

Note- the length of the two columns I want to match is not the same.

```
df1
  postcode brand
1 znuee    soony 
2 eusjk    nike
3 zieum    addidas
4 psosk    ferrari

df2
  pcd      brand
1 dodkm    soony 
2 eusjk    nike
3 sjksj    addidas
4 psosk    ferrari
```

Output:

```
newdf
  pcd      brand
1 eusjk    nike
2 psosk    ferrari
```

my attempt but i get a mismatch length on the columns

```
newdf = (df2['postcode'] == df1).all(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Do i need to use some kind of loopup function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can perform an inner [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging):

```
In [134]:
df1.merge(df2, left_on=['postcode', 'brand'], right_on=['pcd', 'brand'])

Out[134]:
  postcode    brand    pcd
0    eusjk     nike  eusjk
1    psosk  ferrari  psosk
```

You can then drop the 'postcode' column or rename it first:

```
In [136]:

df1.rename(columns={'postcode':'pcd'}).merge(df2)
Out[136]:
     pcd    brand
0  eusjk     nike
1  psosk  ferrari
```

Comment: that did the job. I still dont understand why they would call this "merge", should it not be called "converge" ?

Comment: You're merging on columns/index, you can specify the criteria for merging on lhs and rhs, if there are column names that match then it will match these and the default type of merge is inner so only values that are present on both sides

Comment: @Boosted_d16 don't break a sweat, if it's not food, money or health it isn't important. I seem to be getting random downvotes every couple weeks